changing a time from CET to BST without having a date
I wish to change some times from CET to BST without having a date (to be more specific I do have a date but that is already in BST from another dataset so gets complicated). My issue is that once I change by entrytime in date and time form it shifts back a day which moves my start time a day before the event begun.
date         entrytime 
20240812     00:00     
20240811     00:08     

I've tried using the following by pretty sure I cant do that because I need to enter the date and time here;
myTime = format(strptime(livescorematches$starttime, format = "%F:%T"), "%T")
with_tz(myTime, tzone = "Europe/London")

This would then leave me with
date         entrytime 
20240812     23:00     
20240811     23:08    


Convert the BST date back to CET, add the CET time to that CET date and convert both to UTC?

I'm not sure I'm familiar with how changing the timezone of a date?

@UweKeim If i start with set dates as CET when i then convert my date and times back to UTC i lose a day off my dates which puts me 24 hours out?

Maybe with_tz(ymd_hm(paste(df$date, df$entrytime), tz="CET"), "UTC")?

@AndreWildberg Same problem, as before, the date is not in CET format so passing the date will convert the date/time to be 24 before. Eg "2024-08-11 22:00:00 UTC" "2024-08-10 22:08:00 UTC" when it should be "2024-08-12 22:00:00 UTC" "2024-08-11 22:08:00 UTC"

"2024-08-12 00:00:00" - 24 is "2024-08-11 00:00:00", from CET to UTC is -2, so it changes to "2024-08-11 22:00:00". You want to not change the time when changing timezones? Then use force_tz(ymd_hm(paste(df$date, df$entrytime), tz="CET"), "UTC")

@AndreWildberg You're not getting what I'm asking for here. My original date is in British/GMT form, my time is from another dataset in CET form. I need to convert one to match the other else we are wrong, so we cannot pass both date and time in the same function else we are out. UTC is also not BST, I only need to take 1 hour off the time

You're right, not easy to get what your want to do. Another guess maybe format(with_tz(ymd_hm(paste(df$date, df$entrytime), tz="Europe/London"), "UTC"), "%H:%M")?

@AndreWildberg Looks like it does the job

My assumption: you need to take one hour off the time, put it in your date and set the timezone to "Europe/London".
A not-so-elegant possible solution (hope it helps):
library(tidyverse) # lubridate

# Sample data -------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- tribble(
  ~date,   ~entrytime,
  "20240812", "00:00",     
  "20240811", "00:08",
  "20240810", "16:20")

# Workaround code ---------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    dttm_cet = if_else(
      hm(entrytime) - hours(1) < 0,
      hm(entrytime) + hours(23),
      hm(entrytime) - hours(1)),
    
    dttm_cet = as_datetime(ymd(date)) + dttm_cet,
    dttm_cet = force_tz(dttm_cet, tzone = "Europe/London"))

# Outputs -----------------------------------------------------------------
my_df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   date     entrytime dttm_cet           
#>   <chr>    <chr>     <dttm>             
#> 1 20240812 00:00     2024-08-12 23:00:00
#> 2 20240811 00:08     2024-08-11 23:08:00
#> 3 20240810 16:20     2024-08-10 15:20:00

tz(my_df$dttm_cet)
#> [1] "Europe/London"

Created on 2024-08-20 with reprex v2.1.0
